# got text from paypal telling me i paid for something i didn't

Tags: scams

I just received a text from paypal telling me I just paid around $25 to some game company. There was a link to a receipt.  I looked up the number the text came from and Google tells me it was Paypal, and the URL indeed pointed to paypal.  The linked receipt shows a visa debit sale ("Chip Read, Signature verified") but I do not recognize the last four digits shown for the CC number.

What kind of a scam is this?  If this was to my e-mail address I would ignore it, as I sometimes get strangers signing up for various services with my e-mail, but since this was my phone number I am a bit more hesitant to think it was a mistake.  Is this something I should be worried about or report to someone?  I don't use Paypal.

Comment: Did you log into PayPal *independently of any links* (aka just go directly to `www.paypal.com`, or open their app) to check your account?

Comment: @RonJohn I don't have a paypal account. i took the link to the receipt, erased out the domain part and typed "www.paypal.com" back in.

Comment: If you don't have a paypal account, then you can't pay via paypal... This is some sort of phishing attempt.

Comment: @RonJohn Somebody is phishing by making a real purchase through paypal and using a random (my) phone number?

Comment: It could be, or they want you to click the link and then log into "PayPay" with your real credentials (them not knowing that you don't use PayPal).

Comment: Hanlons Razor - It's also possible someone miskeyed their phone number as OPs and PayPal has crappy verification processes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a PayPal account you are probably safe *as long as you don't click any links or provide information*. This is either a phishing attempt or a wrong number.

You should just do routine checks of your credit, debit, and banking accounts for any unusual transactions. If there is one, dispute it with your vendor (not PayPal).

Answer (score 2):

**At the moment (Feb 2021) it's really common to get these scam texts**.

I get 20-30 a week.

Obviously, just delete and forget, like any spam / scam-spam.

(I don't know, or care that much, how fishing like this has migrated from email to phone texts. But it's the current thing.)